# Нужна ли запятая: "Как думаешь, сколько этому парню лет?"

Tags: пунктуация

*Как думаешь, сколько этому парню лет?*

Answer (score 1):

Как думаешь, сколько этому парню лет?

Запятая ставится в СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, СКОЛЬКО в роли союзного слова.

Answer (score 0):

Как думаешь, сколько этому парню лет?
Абсолютно согласна. Это сложноподчинённое предложение. Главное - "Как думаешь", придаточное - "сколько этому парню лет". Ставим вопрос от главного: думаешь О ЧЁМ?. Определяем вид придаточного как изъяснительное. Запятая ставится перед союзным словом "сколько", выраженным относительным местоимением.